# Is there a Makefile-level "for" loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, makefile

Currently, the only way I know how to loop in `Makefile`s is to just invoke the shell's for loop:

```
BIN_TARGETS=foo bar baz

bin: $(BIN_TARGETS)

run: bin
        for FILE in $(BIN_TARGETS) ; do ./$$FILE ; done
```

The problem with this is that `make` will simply invoke the shell's for loop, echoing the entire for loop, and then each program runs and outputs its output (and if there are any errors, they are only reported at the end of the loop and only for the last program in the loop):

```
$ make run
for FILE in foo bar baz ; do ./$FILE ; done
output of foo
output of bar
output of baz
```

Is there any `Makefile`-level `for` loop that would essentially be the exact equivalent of this?:

```
run: bin
        ./foo
        ./bar
        ./baz
```

which would output this:

```
$ make run
./foo
output of foo
./bar
output of bar
./baz
output of baz
```

and would report any error as it happens.

Comment: By "report error" do you mean "abort"? Because the shell loop will output errors/etc. as they happen but make won't abort on them.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Yes, basically. By "report", I really meant the `Makefile:XX: recipe for target 'run' failed` `make: *** [run] Error 27` message.

Comment: You can get that failure behavior with the shell loop by using `./$FILE || exit $?` as the loop body I believe.

Comment: @EtanReisner: But that doesn't solve the other problems.

Comment: Which other problems? The echo of the whole loop at the start?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Yes. But the question isn't asking for a workaround. It's asking if there is an actual Makefile-level for-loop construct. I can find workarounds on my own.

Answer (score 1):

make does have a loop but not one that will do what you want.

make has `$(foreach)` but that's a make-level construct that will loop over make syntax/etc. not shell-level stuff.

A `define` would let you define the body of the recipe the way you want and use it in your recipe but I can't come up with a way to generate a multi-line define from within make.

This will work (in terms of desired behavior) but I can't get this to be created during a make run.

```
define RECIPE
./foo
./bar
./baz
endef

all:
        $(RECIPE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into `define` and see what I can do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
BIN_TARGETS:=foo bar baz

define CMD
    $1

endef

bin: $(BIN_TARGETS)

run: bin
    $(foreach t, $(BIN_TARGETS), $(call CMD,./$(t)))
```

The `CMD` variable is necessary to provide the right separation between the commands. I've not found a way to do it more concisely.

If `foo`, `bar`, `baz` contain:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo output of $0
```

Then running `make run` outputs:

```
./foo
output of ./foo
./bar
output of ./bar
./baz
output of ./baz
```

Answer (score 0):

One method I came up with is to use phony targets with made-up suffixes:

```
run: $(addsuffix .run,$(BIN_TARGETS))

%.run: %
        ./$*
```

This, however, gets messy when there are multiple possible matches for something like `foo.run`. The only thing this does differently is it compiles and runs one file, then the next, rather than compiling all of them and then running all of them.